# Modifying only the beginning of an image and not it fully, as I wish

Tags: c++

I currently have some code that reads an image stored in the tga format, then do something with it and then store it in a new tga file.
The problem is that only the bottom one third is being modified, the other two thirds are equal to the original image. Here is the code:

```
int size = width*height*bpp;
char imageArray [size];
char * arrayPtr = &imageArray[0];
......
for (int x=0; x<width; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
        imageArray [x*height + 3*y] = 255;
        imageArray [x*height + 3*y + 1] = 0;
        imageArray [x*height + 3*y + 2] = 0;
    }
}
fileWriter.write (arrayPtr, size);
```

As can be seen inside the loops, I am modifying each color value, in this case making it into a single color image. Unfortunately only the bottom third will be modified, even with the number of loop iterations being equal to the number of pixels, and doing three operations by iteration, the number of it is equal to the number of bytes of the original image.
So I have no idea of what I am doing wrong and would be thankful for any recommendations.

Comment: I'd guess it's because of your mysterious factor of 3 in front of `y` in your index. Why do you look up `x*height + 3*y` instead of just `x*height + y`? Also, you only seem to iterate over `index = 0 -> width*height`, but the size of your array is `width*height*bpp`, so you only cover the whole range if `bpp == 1`. It sounds like `bpp = 3` so you're only going over the first 1/3rd of your image.

Answer (score 1):

The whole offset has to be multiplied by `bpp`, not only `y`:

```
    imageArray [bpp*(x*height + y)] = 255;
    imageArray [bpp*(x*height + y) + 1] = 0;
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem now, but it relies on some assumptions about how you are bringing in your data and what `bpp` means.

You are trying to loop over every pixel here and update the 3 values.
You set `size = width*height*bpp` where I can only assume `bpp` means bits-per-pixel and is the 3 showing up in your loop. Try stepping through this with `x=1` and `y=0`. If the data is being layed out contiguously like:
`RGB @ x=0,y=0; RGB @ x=1,y=0; ...` then you can see you end up writing over your data from the first iteration of the loop. Everytime you nest the loop, the index should get multiplied entirely by the next levels dimension. Just replace `x*height + 3*y` with `(x*height + y)*bpp` assuming `bpp = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the order that bytes a stored in the image array.

Your formulation suggest a by-column/by-row/by-color. But it can also be by-row/by-column/by-color or even by-color/by-row/by-column.

The index formulation should be

- `x*(b*h)+y*b+c`
- `y*(b*w)+x*b+c`
- `c*(w*h)+y*h+x`

(b, w ,and h are color bytes, width and height)

Note how indexes cumulate in the sums. You have at least forgotten one multiplication, assuming the order is correct.